# Dynamic mapping for BeanIO in Camel on windows

Tags: apache-camel

I working on CSV to CSV file conversion using beanIO camel compnnet, is there any way or workaround to load mapping files on fly or at runtime in marshal /unmarshal endpoint in camel route.

Hard coding of files is working for me but not the with placeholder

.unmarshal(new  BeanIODataFormat("file://C://Camel//Dev//mapping//unmarshlling//inputMapping.xml", "xyz"))

OR

.to("dataformat:beanio:unmarshal?mapping='file://C://Camel//Dev//mapping//unmarshlling//inputMapping.xml'?streamName=xyz")

is working but

.unmarshal(new  BeanIODataFormat("{{file name}}", "xyz"))

OR

.to("dataformat:beanio:unmarshal?mapping=("{{file name}}"?streamName=xyz")
Is not working for me , I want to put mapping file as in put and which will load from external folder please help

Comment: See this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

Comment: Thanks Claus, I tried the things mentioned in link ...